# How to sort object in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I sort my array data

Here is my structure data

array 
    -> object
            -> array

I want to sort By tags  if tags not empty it should be display first

```
 "data": [
         {
            "id": 2
            "name": "product2",
            "tags": [],
        },
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "product",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Promoion product",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "product",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "new product",
                }
            ],
        },

    ]
```

I want my output look like this

```
 "data": [
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "product",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Promoion product",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "product",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "new product",
                }
            ],
        },
          {
            "id": 2
            "name": "product2",
            "tags": [],
        },
    ]
```

tags [] should be the last one I try to use lodash but still not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just sort it by tags length:

```
const formatedData = data.sort((a,b) => b.tags.length - a.tags.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort descending by tags length

```js
obj.data.sort((a, b) => b.tags.length - a.tags.length);
console.log(obj.data);
```

```html
<script>
const obj = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "product2",
            "tags": [],
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "product",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Promoion product",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "product",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "new product",
                }
            ],
        },

    ]
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by checking the length and move only empty tags to bottom and leave the rest unsorted.

```js
var data = [{ id: 2, name: "product2", tags: [] }, { id: 3, name: "product", tags: [{ id: 3, name: "Promoion product" }] }, { id: 1, name: "product", tags: [{ id: 4, name: "new product" }] }];

data.sort((a, b) => !a.tags.length - !b.tags.length);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```